# Google Sheets - Dynamic function to find name of a Column (based on values in said column)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

It seems like a fairly easy function, but I simply cannot wrap my head around it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDWdu.png - Picture to help you imagine.

I have 2 columns filled with data (**B3:C**), and I have another column (**E**), where I input data (data validation from the **B3:C** dataset). I need a function (in column **F**) that will match the name of one of the columns (**B2** or **C2**), based on the value in **E**.

Example: If **E4** is in the column **B**, then **F4** is **B2**.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Maybe something like `=INDEX(VLOOKUP(E2:E5,SPLIT(FLATTEN({B3:B7&"|"&B2},{C3:C7&"|"&C2}),"|"),2))`

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work :(

Comment: @JvdV add an `is_sorted` parameter of `false` in `vlookup()` to get the correct results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, including `filter(match())` and `vlookup()`. Try this fill-down formula:

`=filter($B$2:$C$2, { match(E2, $B$3:$B, 0), match(E2, $C$3:$C, 0) } )`

...or this array formula that fills all of the column automatically:

```
=arrayformula( 
  iferror( 
    vlookup( 
      E2:E, 
      { 
        B3:B, iferror(B3:B/0, B2); 
        C3:C, iferror(C3:C/0, C2) 
      }, 
      2, 
      false 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I have been looking for!